# Utilizing Git for multiple development places

Tags: eclipse, git, workflow, synchronization, dvcs

I want to utilize git in my development workflow. I'm using Eclipse Juno.
I'm coming from CVS, but see lots of benefits from distributed VCS.
I'm reading Pro Git book, have read quite bit of it to start using it, but somehow something does not work the way I think it should to.
I'm doing well with it on single machine, but fail when I do remote repository sync.

This is what I want to achieve:

I have two PC-s, HOME & WORK. I want to develop on both PC, so chose git to sync them as well.
I created repository on the THUMB drive, and cloned it on HOME & WORK.

now, I want to develop on either HOME or WORK, commit locally, sync with THUMB, and then sync with another PC (HOME or WORK).

what commands should I issue to do this? (for example WORK -> THUMB -> HOME)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic workflow is commit locally using:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Commit message"
```

Until done, then:

```
# Push the 'master' branch to the 'thumb' repository
$ git push thumb master
```

Now switch the thumb drive to the other pc and then:

```
# Pull from the 'thumb' drive into your local repo
$ git pull thumb master
```

Comment: this is the error I get when I try to "git push origin master"

Comment: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repositories denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
the work tree to HEAD.

Comment: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
other way.

To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To file:///G:\repo\Test
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)

Comment: The repository on your thumb drive should be a bare repository (ie. only a repo, no working copy). Then it will not have a checked out branch, so this error would not occur. Such a repo can normally be created using ```git init --bare```

Answer (score 2):

So in your case THUMB is like an online central repository. If you cloned both WORK and HOME from the THUMB, it should be set up as a remote named `origin` on both PC-s, which is great.

So now when you make changes on WORK, you need to `git push`. It should automatically *push* the changes you made to the `origin`, so in your case to THUMB.

Then on HOME you need to either `git fetch` and then manually merge your `master` with `origin/master` or `git pull`. This is a matter of preference and I am sure that Pro Git explains it better than I could.

Comment: this is exctly what I used to do, but here is strange thing that Eclipses's EGIT does:

I modify file, do "Add to Index" (stage), do "Commit".
inspect local repository wit Git GUI. everything is as it should be.

then I do "PushUpstream". check remote repository with Git GUI.

!!! Change is pushed but remote's staging area contains change commiting wich effectively reverts push operations back. I need to unstage & revert remote to complete pushing. don't think it's the way it was meant to be.